# Split a list of integers into sublists of equal sum in linear time

Tags: algorithm

I found an algorithm to do this in the following way:

1. Given list l, compute its sum s.
2. Compute the following table:

(s,acc)

1. (s,0)
2. (s-x1,x1)
3. (s-x1-x2,x1+x2)

   ...

n. (s-x1-...x_n-1,x1+x2+...+x_n-1)

while at each step you check whether the left element of the pair is equal to the second.

Then, this algorithm determines in linear time if your list can be splitted in two sublists  so that each sublists sums the same quantity.

I've trying for a while to proof this formally. However, I'm beginning to think that this may only be valid for natural numbers and not for integers.

1. Can you confirm this view?
2. Can you give an algorithm to do this for integers and for linear complexity?

**Edit (my solution up to now)**

```
fun check_list :: "int list ⇒ int ⇒ int ⇒ bool" where
"check_list [] n acc = False" |
"check_list (x#xs) n acc = (if n = acc then True else (check_list xs (n-x) (acc+x)))"

fun linear_split :: "int list ⇒ bool" where
"linear_split [] = False" |
"linear_split [x] = False" |
"linear_split (x # xs) = check_list xs (sum_list xs) x"
```

Comment: There's no problem unless the algorithm stops when the right side is greater than the left side.

Comment: I'm sorry but did you mention that the list is sorted?

Comment: Consider this input: [5,10,5]. Your steps are: (20,0) -> (15,5) -> (5,15) -> (0,20). You never see (10,10). Am I right?

Comment: @Emadpres yes but then the algorithm tells you it is not possible to split this list into two lists with equal sums. Indeed, possible splits are [50],[100,50] | [50,100],[50] and none of them have equal sums (there are similar problems to this one, perhaps you're confusing with them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asked to divide the list (as it is) into two parts without reordering the items.

> I've trying for a while to proof this formally.

Your algorithm is correct since you're basically **covering every single possible split** by basically moving a separator along the list:

```
 | O O O  split 1
 O | O O  split 2
 O O | O  split 3
 O O O |  split 4
```

> Can you give an algorithm to do this for integers and for linear complexity?

Your algorithm works for integers as well. Again, because you're inspecting every possible solution and its complexity is linear since you're just iterating over list twice (first time for calculating `sum`)