# Proving the correctness of an algorithm to partition lists in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, proof-of-correctness

I trying to prove correct an algorithm to split a list of integers into sublists of equal sum in linear time. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53143820/split-a-list-of-integers-into-sublists-of-equal-sum-in-linear-time) you can see the algorithm I have chosen to do so.

I would like to get some feedback regarding:

1. The convenience of my definition for the splitting function.
2. The "induction" hypothesis to use in my situation.

Please, bear in mind that up to now I have only worked with apply-scripts and not with Isar proofs.

Here is a preliminary implementation of the algorithm and the correctness definition:

```
definition
  "ex_balanced_sum xs = (∃ ys zs. sum_list ys = sum_list zs ∧ 
                                  xs = ys @ zs ∧ ys ≠ [] ∧ zs ≠ [])"


 fun check_list :: "int list ⇒ int ⇒ int ⇒ bool" where
    "check_list [] n acc = False" |
    "check_list (x#xs) n acc = (if n = acc then True else (check_list xs (n-x) (acc+x)))"

fun linear_split :: "int list ⇒ bool" where
"linear_split [] = False" |
"linear_split [x] = False" |
"linear_split (x # xs) = check_list xs (sum_list xs) x"
```

The theorem to prove is as follows:

```
lemma linear_correct: "linear_split xs ⟷ ex_balanced_sum xs"
```

If I reason for instance for the first implication as:

```
lemma linear_correct_1: "linear_split xs ⟹ ex_balanced_sum xs"
  apply(induction xs rule: linear_split.induct)
```

Then I get a list of subgoals that I think are not appropriate:

1. linear_split [] ⟹ ex_balanced_sum []
2. ⋀x. linear_split [x] ⟹ ex_balanced_sum [x]
3. ⋀x v va. linear_split (x # v # va) ⟹ ex_balanced_sum (x # v # va)

In particular, these subgoals don't have an induction hypothesis! (am I right?). I tried to perform a different induction by just writing `apply(induction xs)` but then the goals look as:

1. linear_split [] ⟹ ex_balanced_sum []
2. ⋀a xs. (linear_split xs ⟹ ex_balanced_sum xs) ⟹ linear_split (a # xs) ⟹ ex_balanced_sum (a # xs)

Here the hypothesis is also not an induction hypothesis since it is assuming an implication.

So, what is the best way to define this function to get a nice induction hypothesis?

**Edit (a one-function version)**

```
fun check :: "int list ⇒ int ⇒ int ⇒ bool" where
"check [] n acc = False" |
"check [x] n acc = False" |
"check (x # y # xs) n acc = (if n-x = acc+x then True else check (y # xs) (n-x) (acc+x))"

definition "linear_split xs = check xs (sum_list xs) 0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**

I was able to prove the theorem `linear_correct` for a function (`splitl`) that is very similar to the function `check` in the statement of the question. Unfortunately, I would prefer not to make any attempts to convert the proof into an apply script.

The proof below is the first proof that came to my mind after I started investigating the question. Thus, there may exist better proofs.

---

**Proof Outline**

The proof is based on the induction based on the length of the list. In particular, assume

`splitl xs (sum_list xs) 0 ⟹ ex_balanced_sum xs`

holds for all lists with the length less than `l`. If `l = 1`, then the result is easy to show. Assume, that `l>=2`. Then the list can be expressed in the form `x#v#xs`. In this case if it is possible to split the list using `splitl`, then it can be shown (`splitl_reduce`) that either

`"splitl ((x + v)#xs) (sum_list ((x + v)#xs)) 0"` (1)

or

`"x = sum_list (v#xs)"` (2).

Thus, the proof proceeds by cases for (1) and (2). For (1), the length of the list is `(x + v)#xs)` is `l-1`. Hence, by the induction hypothesis `ex_balanced_sum (x + v)#xs)`. Therefore, by the definition of `ex_balanced_sum`, also `ex_balanced_sum x#v#xs`. For (2), it can be easily seen that the list can be expressed as `[x]@(v#xs)` and, in this case, given (2), it satisfies the conditions of `ex_balanced_sum` by definition.

The proof for the other direction is similar and based on the converse of the lemma associated with (1) and (2) above: if `"splitl ((x + v)#xs) (sum_list ((x + v)#xs)) 0"` or `"x = sum_list (v#xs)"`, then `"splitl (x#v#xs) (sum_list (x#v#xs)) 0"`.

---

```
theory so_ptcoaatplii
imports  Complex_Main

begin

definition
  "ex_balanced_sum xs = 
  (∃ ys zs. sum_list ys = sum_list zs ∧ xs = ys @ zs ∧ ys ≠ [] ∧ zs ≠ [])"

fun splitl :: "int list ⇒ int ⇒ int ⇒ bool" where
  "splitl [] s1 s2 = False" |
  "splitl [x] s1 s2 = False" |
  "splitl (x # xs) s1 s2 = ((s1 - x = s2 + x) ∨ splitl xs (s1 - x) (s2 + x))"

lemma splitl_reduce:
  assumes "splitl (x#v#xs) (sum_list (x#v#xs)) 0" 
  shows "splitl ((x + v)#xs) (sum_list ((x + v)#xs)) 0 ∨ x = sum_list (v#xs)"
proof -
  from assms have prem_cases: 
    "((x = sum_list (v#xs)) ∨ splitl (v#xs) (sum_list (v#xs)) x)" by auto
  {
    assume "splitl (v#xs) (sum_list (v#xs)) x"
    then have "splitl ((x + v)#xs) (sum_list ((x + v)#xs)) 0"
    proof(induction xs arbitrary: x v)
      case Nil then show ?case by simp
    next
      case (Cons a xs) then show ?case by simp
    qed
  } 
  with prem_cases show ?thesis by auto
qed

(*Sledgehammered*)
lemma splitl_expand:
  assumes "splitl ((x + v)#xs) (sum_list ((x + v)#xs)) 0 ∨ x = sum_list (v#xs)"
  shows "splitl (x#v#xs) (sum_list (x#v#xs)) 0"
  by (smt assms list.inject splitl.elims(2) splitl.simps(3) sum_list.Cons)

lemma splitl_to_sum: "splitl xs (sum_list xs) 0 ⟹ ex_balanced_sum xs"
proof(induction xs rule: length_induct)
  case (1 xs) show ?case
  proof-
    obtain x v xst where x_xst: "xs = x#v#xst" 
      by (meson "1.prems" splitl.elims(2))
    have main_cases:
      "splitl ((x + v)#xst) (sum_list ((x + v)#xst)) 0 ∨ x = sum_list (v#xst)"
      by (rule splitl_reduce, insert x_xst "1.prems", rule subst)
    {
      assume "splitl ((x + v)#xst) (sum_list ((x + v)#xst)) 0"
      with "1.IH" x_xst have "ex_balanced_sum ((x + v)#xst)" by simp
      then obtain yst zst where 
        yst_zst: "(x + v)#xst = yst@zst" 
        and sum_yst_eq_sum_zst: "sum_list yst = sum_list zst"
        and yst_ne: "yst ≠ []" 
        and zst_ne: "zst ≠ []"
        unfolding ex_balanced_sum_def by auto
      then obtain ystt where ystt: "yst = (x + v)#ystt" 
        by (metis append_eq_Cons_conv)
      with sum_yst_eq_sum_zst have "sum_list (x#v#ystt) = sum_list zst" by simp
      moreover have "xs = (x#v#ystt)@zst" using x_xst yst_zst ystt by auto
      moreover have "(x#v#ystt) ≠ []" by simp
      moreover with zst_ne have "zst ≠ []" by simp
      ultimately have "ex_balanced_sum xs" unfolding ex_balanced_sum_def by blast
    }
    note prem = this
    {
      assume "x = sum_list (v#xst)"
      then have "sum_list [x] = sum_list (v#xst)" by auto
      moreover with x_xst have "xs = [x] @ (v#xst)" by auto
      ultimately have "ex_balanced_sum xs" using ex_balanced_sum_def by blast
    }
    with prem main_cases show ?thesis by blast
  qed
qed


lemma sum_to_splitl: "ex_balanced_sum xs ⟹ splitl xs (sum_list xs) 0"
proof(induction xs rule: length_induct)
  case (1 xs) show ?case
  proof -
    from "1.prems" ex_balanced_sum_def obtain ys zs where 
      ys_zs: "xs = ys@zs"
      and sum_ys_eq_sum_zs: "sum_list ys = sum_list zs"
      and ys_ne: "ys ≠ []"
      and zs_ne: "zs ≠ []"
      by blast
    have prem_cases: "∃y v yst. ys = (y#v#yst) ∨ (∃y. ys = [y])"
      by (metis remdups_adj.cases ys_ne)
    {
      assume "∃y. ys = [y]"
      then have "splitl xs (sum_list xs) 0"
        using splitl.elims(3) sum_ys_eq_sum_zs ys_zs zs_ne by fastforce
    }
    note prem = this
    {
      assume "∃y v yst. ys = (y#v#yst)"
      then obtain y v yst where y_v_yst: "ys = (y#v#yst)" by auto 
      then have 
        "sum_list ((y + v)#yst) = sum_list zs ∧ ((y + v)#yst) ≠ [] ∧ zs ≠ []"
        using sum_ys_eq_sum_zs zs_ne by auto
      then have ebs_ypv: "ex_balanced_sum (((y + v)#yst)@zs)"
        using ex_balanced_sum_def by blast
      have l_ypv: "length (((y + v)#yst)@zs) < length xs" 
        by (simp add: y_v_yst ys_zs)
      from l_ypv ebs_ypv have 
        "splitl (((y + v)#yst)@zs) (sum_list (((y + v)#yst)@zs)) 0"
        by (rule "1.IH"[THEN spec, rule_format])    
      with splitl_expand have splitl_ys_exp: 
        "splitl ((y#v#yst)@zs) (sum_list ((y#v#yst)@zs)) 0"
        by (metis Cons_eq_appendI)
      from ys_zs have "splitl xs (sum_list xs) 0" 
        by (rule ssubst, insert y_v_yst splitl_ys_exp, simp)
    }
    with prem prem_cases show ?thesis by auto
  qed  
qed

lemma linear_correct: "ex_balanced_sum xs ⟷ splitl xs (sum_list xs) 0"
  using splitl_to_sum sum_to_splitl by auto

end
```

Comment: ok, apparently the induction scheme I was missing was length induction

Comment: @Javier I had some free time during the last weekend and decided to do a minor revision of the answers that I posted on this website, including my answers to your questions. I have to admit that when I answer the questions on this website, usually, I optimise my answers for the speed of delivery, rather than the quality of the code. Thus, normally, I use `sledgehammer` at almost every step. The amendments replace some of the instances of the use of sledgehammer with more thoughtful approaches. However, hopefully, you have already made the necessary amendments in your own code base.